# Is a RDS / EC2 Combo inside the same VPC faster than a RDS / EC2 combo in separated VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any difference in terms of speed / latency, for a web app, let's say written in PHP / MySQL with Nginx, if RDS / EC2 are or are not in the same VPC.

Answer (score 0):

**Same VPC**

If they are in the same VPC, it will be a tad bit faster, as you don't need to wrap your requests with an additional security later and going through additional routing tables. Every microsecond counts when it comes to scaling and tuning the application. You also get better control on placing your instances in the right AZs.

You can gain additional benefits of keeping them in the same VPC by placing the instances in a same placement group. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html

**Different VPC**

If they are in different VPC + Same region, you need to go through the head ache for provisioning additional security rules. If different VPC + Different region, its going to be a lot slower.